# Web vr chrome not found

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webvr

I am trying to enter web vr mode by clicking the button in the following link https://threejs.org/examples/?q=vr#webvr_ballshooter
but got "vr not found" in the text button.
I am running chrome version 69 (64-bit) on macOs and I already enable some flags:

- enable-webvr
- webxr
- webxr-gamepad-support
- webxr-orientation-sensor-device
- webxr-hit-test

Comment: Have you connected a VR device?

Comment: No i haven't, do i need to connect one to have the "enter vr" button?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know if there is a way to enter vr mode directly on the chrome browser by clicking on the button (with the view split in two) ?
I saw someone in a video who manage to do it but i don't know how.

Comment: I found my answer, by downloading the webvr api emulation I can enter vr mode in the browser without a device